# Some PnP cmdlets not being found

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

We are running PnP PowerShell scripts against SharePoint Online and have had a snag with some of the cmdlets from the PnP library where some of them are not being found (as if they have been removed for the library or it's accessing a previous library than what's listed).

Here's code up to the error:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $NewSite -Credentials $Credentials  ### Works
Add-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin -Owners @($Owner1, $Owner2)     ### Works
Remove-PnPPage -Identity "Home" -Recycle -Force            ### Errors Out (below)
Add-PnPPage -Name "NewHomePage"
```

The strange error from Remove-PnPPage (Add-PnPPage will throw same error):

> Error: The term 'Remove-PnPPage' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the  path is
> correct and try again.

I checked the version we have using Get-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell... and lists only one version, the latest (as of this post).

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell* -ListAvailable | Select-Object Name,Version | Sort-Object Version -Descending

Name                          Version    
----                          -------    
SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 3.29.2101.0
```

I have Uninstalled the SharePointPnpPowerShellOnline module and then reinstalled it without any luck of working.  Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module you are using i.e `SharepoinPnPPowerShellOnline` is a legacy version.
Please try to use `PnP.Powershell`.

Please refer this document for the deprecated and updated commands: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/upgrading.html

Comment: Thank you.  Even though this feels like an "obvious" answer to my question, there is a lot of old documentation from the SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline that is out on the Internet that leads to this confusion since some of the cmdlets are used in both libraries.